# AppleScript - How to loop thru column and change vaules based on existing value in Numbers

Tags: applescript

I am new to AppleScript and can not figure out how to loop thru a Numbers spreadsheet column, column "C" in this case, from top to bottom and change its value based on its existing value. I have looked online but without success.

Here is what I have so far but it doesn't work. It will only change the value in cell C11.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Numbers"
        activate
        tell the first table of the active sheet of document 1
            repeat with i from 2 to count of cells of column "c"
                if value of cell i is equal to "National League" then
                    set the value of cell i of column "C" to "2"
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell    
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out: `of column "C"`

You need to change:

```
if value of cell i is equal to "National League" then
```

To:

```
if value of cell i of column "C" is equal to "National League" then
```

Comment: That was the problem. Now the script works as expected.